# How do I get rid of this Notice: Array to string conversion in... error

Tags: php, arrays

I have seen a ton of people like me posting about this issue on this forum.

I have not been able to resolve my own issue from any of those examples.

For instance, this code below is from a page called review.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "DEBUG POST DATA: <pre>".print_r($_POST, 1)."</pre>";
if(isset($_POST['employeename']))
$employeename = $_POST['employeename'];
if(isset($_POST['email']))
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(isset($_POST['ttitle']))
$ttitle = $_POST['ttitle'];
$rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];
$row2IDs = $_POST['row2IDs'];

echo $employeename .'<br>';
echo $ttitle .'<br> <hr width=400 align=left>';


$rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];

foreach ($rowIDs as $id) {
    $sourcename = $_POST['sourcename' . $id];
    $sourceaddress = $_POST['sourceaddress' . $id];
    $income = $_POST['income' . $id];

    echo 'Name:     '. $sourcename . '<br />';
    echo 'Address:   '. $sourceaddress . '<br />';
    echo 'Income:   '. $income . '<br /><br>';
}

foreach ($row2IDs as $id) {
    $spousename = $_POST['spousename' . $id];
    $spouseAddress = $_POST['spouseAddress' . $id];
    $spouseIncome = $_POST['spouseIncome' . $id];

    echo 'Name:     '. $spousename . '<br />';
    echo 'Address:   '. $spouseAddress . '<br />';
    echo 'spouseIncome:   '. $spouseIncome . '<br /><br>';
     echo 'Your email: '. $email . '<br /><br>';
 }
?>

<body>
<form action='final.php' method = 'POST'>
<input type="hidden" name="employeename" value="<?php echo $employeename; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="ttitle" value="<?php echo $ttitle; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sourcename[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['sourcename' . $id]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sourceaddress[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['sourceaddress' . $id]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="income[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['income' . $id]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="spousename[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['spousename' . $id]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="spouseAddress[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['spouseAddress' . $id]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="spouseIncome[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['spouseIncome' . $id]; ?>">

<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Return to correct changes</a> <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

When I run it, I get:
***Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\forms\final.php on line 70***

The error points to this line:
   ***if( mysqli_stmt_execute($sth) ) {...***

which is a part of the following insert statement:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `mydb`.`wp_mytable` ( `employeeID`'
     . ', `sourcename`, `sourceaddress`, `income`,`spousename`,`spouseAddress`,`spouseincome` )'
     . ' VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )';

if( $sth = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql) ) {
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'sssssss'
      ,$last_id
      ,$_POST["sourcename"]
      ,$_POST["sourceaddress"]
      ,$_POST["income"]
      ,$_POST["spousename"]
      ,$_POST["spouseAddress"]
      ,$_POST["spouseIncome"]
   );
```

I also know that I need to do a FOR loop on these fields like this one below that I am passing as an array in hidden form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sourcename[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['sourcename' . $id]; ?>">
```

How do incorporate a foreach loop on these hidden form fields on review.php so that users can store as many rows as possible without these errors getting in the way?

Thank you

Comment: `$_POST["sourcename"]` etc are arrays not stings. thats what the `[]` in `name="sourcename[]"` does

Comment: Hi @nogad, thanks for your response.

If I understand you correctly, I am doing it correctly, yes?

If yes, why do you think I am getting the error that I am getting?

Comment: its correct if you want an array, but yhen it wont be correct for the query you have

Comment: @nogad, thanks a lot but can you help please?

I probably need something like: $_POST["sourcename"][] but what goes into []?

Comment: i really dont understand the code, are you inserting one row or multiple rows?

Comment: @nogad, if you look a the hidden fields, any of those fields that has [] can insert one or more rows at once.

That's what this line and a few others do:

` $sourcename = $_POST['sourcename' . $id];`

But don't know how to use those in the final.php insert script.

Comment: try just drop all the `[]` in the form

Comment: @nogad, I don't know but I will try now.

Comment: Just as I expected, only one record is inserted into the database as opposed to the 3 I was trying to insert.

Comment: thats what i asked before - arg

Comment: and I responded that depending on user's interest, one or more records can be selected and inserted at same time. That's why I showed the code that shows it is an array. I am passing the array as hidden form fields but how to insert those still as arrays into the database.

Comment: please try `var_dump($_POST)` see  how your input name is getting on final.php or where you are receiving these.

Comment: Can you manage to integrate call_user_func_array() into your process?  http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli  This is not my expertise, just a suggestion.