# Issues with Inserting array hidden form values into the database

Tags: php, arrays

We have hidden form fields on our review.php page and we are passing these hidden form fields as an array to the processing page called final.php.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "DEBUG POST DATA: <pre>".print_r($_POST, 1)."</pre>";
if(isset($_POST['employeename']))
$employeename = $_POST['employeename'];
if(isset($_POST['email']))
$email = $_POST['email'];
if(isset($_POST['ttitle']))
$ttitle = $_POST['ttitle'];
$rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];
$row2IDs = $_POST['row2IDs'];

echo $employeename .'<br>';
echo $ttitle .'<br> <hr width=400 align=left>';


$rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];

foreach ($rowIDs as $id) {
    $sourcename = $_POST['sourcename' . $id];
    $sourceaddress = $_POST['sourceaddress' . $id];
    $income = $_POST['income' . $id];

    echo 'Name:     '. $sourcename . '<br />';
    echo 'Address:   '. $sourceaddress . '<br />';
    echo 'Income:   '. $income . '<br /><br>';
}

foreach ($row2IDs as $id) {
    $spousename = $_POST['spousename' . $id];
    $spouseAddress = $_POST['spouseAddress' . $id];
    $spouseIncome = $_POST['spouseIncome' . $id];

    echo 'Name:     '. $spousename . '<br />';
    echo 'Address:   '. $spouseAddress . '<br />';
    echo 'spouseIncome:   '. $spouseIncome . '<br /><br>';
     echo 'Your email: '. $email . '<br /><br>';
 }
?>

<body>
<form action='final.php' method = 'POST'>
<input type="hidden" name="employeename" value="<?php echo $employeename; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="ttitle" value="<?php echo $ttitle; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sourcename[]" value="<?php echo $sourcename; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sourceaddress[]" value="<?php echo $sourceaddress; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="income[]" value="<?php echo $income; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="spousename[]" value="<?php echo $spousename; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="spouseAddress[]" value="<?php echo $spouseAddress; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="spouseIncome[]" value="<?php echo $spouseIncome; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

When I run the code, I get: 
***Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\forms\final.php on line 70***

The error points to this line:

```
if( mysqli_stmt_execute($sth) ) {...
```

which is a part of the following insert statement:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `mydb`.`wp_mytable` ( `employeeID`'
     . ', `sourcename`, `sourceaddress`, `income`,`spousename`,`spouseAddress`,`spouseincome` )'
     . ' VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )';

if( $sth = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql) ) {
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,'sssssss'
      ,$last_id
      ,$_POST["sourcename"]
      ,$_POST["sourceaddress"]
      ,$_POST["income"]
      ,$_POST["spousename"]
      ,$_POST["spouseAddress"]
      ,$_POST["spouseIncome"]
   );
```

I believe I am getting this error because the hidden form fields on review.php is an array but the variables I am attempting to insert into the database is no.

Does anyone know how I can convert the variables to array?

I mean those variables where the hidden form field is designated as array []?

Comment: I don't seem to understand how your script works. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: post your html form

Comment: never mind, it's a repost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429625/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-notice-array-to-string-conversion-in-error

Comment: @Fred-ii-, hi Fred. You are correct. I posted it late last night and didn't get much help. I thought it was because everyone has gone to bed.

I am desperate for help sir.

Comment: error point line is wrong because `mysqli_stmt_execute` return only true or false

Comment: @gaurav, thank you. What should I change it to?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in line but array to string conversion on this line not possible to occur please provide final.php code more &  explain little bit more

Comment: @Condorcho, we have three pages, order.php where users can place orders. They can place one order or more, hence the array.

Then we have another page called review.php. This is where users can review their orders and then click submit if anything is ok. That's where those arrays (not all of them are arrays) are passed as hidden form fields.

Then the last page called final.php.

When a user clicks the submit button, all his or her orders are supposed to be submitted to the database. That's the page I am having issues with.

Comment: @gaurav, that's the execution line but the actual error has to do with those variables passed as $_POST[...].

Some of those need to be passed as array. That's what causing the error. I just don't know how to fix it.